# Change point detection of rasterstack using the Pettitt.test (x) function of Trend package in R

Tags: r

I have a NDVI time series dataset with 38 layers,large rasterstack, and want to detect the change point using the Pettitt.test (x) function of Trend package, but I get an error message when I run the following code:

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(trend)
# example dataset with 27 layers
s <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
s <- stack(s, s* 2, s*3)
ss <- stack(s, s* 2, s*3)
# calculating change point k
fun2 <- function(x){       
        if(length(na.omit(x))<27) return(c(NA))
        pttest <- pettitt.test(ts(na.omit(x)))
        vl <-pttest$estimate
        return(c(vl))
}
p.test<-calc(ss,fun2)
```

It returns the following error

```
Error in setValues(out, x) : 
  values must be numeric, integer, logical or factor
```

why? Is there anybody who can help me to resolve this problem? Thank you!!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, could you share a sample of your data? Just type `dput(head(ss))` in the console and paste the output in your question. That help us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this error is that `pttest$estimate` can be more than one value.
The error goes away if you change the function like this

```
fun3 <- function(x){
        x <- na.omit(x)       
        if (length(x) < 27) return(NA)
        pttest <- pettitt.test(ts(x))
        v <- pttest$estimate
        v[1]
}
p.test<-calc(ss, fun3)
```

Or if you want to have two values, something like this

```
fun4 <- function(x){       
        x <- na.omit(x)       
        if (length(x) < 27) return(c(NA, NA))
        pttest <- pettitt.test(ts(x))
        v <- pttest$estimate
        rep_len(v, 2)
}
p.test<-calc(ss, fun4)
```